# How to call web service wcf

Tags: c#, wcf

I have web serice
http:/localhost:8585/Design_Time_Addresses/Mobios.Medica.Services.Notification/DispositionService//Design_Time_Addresses/Mobios.Medica.Services.Notification/DispositionService

how we call config and sv C#

Answer (score 0):

You can use the svcutil tool to generate proxy files to call the wcf service and retrogradely, or you can call the wcf service by adding a service reference. This is the reference: [Accessing Services Using a WCF Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/accessing-services-using-a-wcf-client).